# 2 spring cloud stream Kafkas for java application

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am new in Kafka and i am not sure how to setup configuration for my application problem.
[image]

I would like to ask how to setup 2 kafkas one for each datacenter. Events and data will be the same difference is only in Data center.I have 1 topic and i have to send data from kafka 1 from DC1 process in application and send it to topic 2 and Kafka 1 and DC1. Everything is the same only region for DC is different so basically i need 2 StreamListeners and 2 producers able decide where to send or receive data.

Do you have any recommendation or links ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use MirrorMaker from DC1 to DC2 rather than make an app produce to both. Otherwise, you risk data failing to get written to one or both Kafka clusters

Comment: Thanks but those DCs represents regions. Its not like backup but each DC means different country so they are splited.

Comment: Okay, if that's the case, then you can create two different KafkaProducer instances from the config

Comment: However, that still doesn't prevent you from writing all data to one cluster, with two different topics, then mirroring one topic over